# I cannot get the Autoban module to work from "Access Denied" or "Page Not Found"

Tags: 9

I must be doing something stupid because there are several thousand users of this module! I need this module badly because just about every night the site gets a hundred or more "page not founds". At present I'm entering them manually in the banned ip address list.

I've searched for documentation on this module without success. What I assume should happen is that, once the threshold level is reached, any watchdog entry matched with a rule will result in an automatically generated ip address ban entry.

Here are the settings I'm using...

**Rule**
*Message pattern :* LIKE page not found
*Referrer pattern :* no entry
*Threshhold:* 1
*User Type:* Anonymous
*IP Ban Provider:* Core Ban

Drupal version 9.4.6
Log Analysis shows no entries but there **are** entries in the log... e.g.
*page not found 10/25/2022 - 16:09 /taxonomy/term/rss.xml Anonymous (not verified)* (? The not verified couldn't be causing the problem, could it? )

**Settings:**
*Exclude dblog types:*
autoban
cron
php
system
user

*Analyses Form Threshold:* 5
*Whitelist:* blank

*Query mode:* LIKE
*Use wildcard :* unchecked

I hope this helps pinpoint what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Message pattern: "page not found" and that's all. (Use message patterns under the Message pattern field). No need to add "LIKE" to the Message patters.

The module will do request "LIKE %page not found%" and when you add "LIKE" to a pattern the module does "LIKE %LIKE page not found%" query and it returns empty data.

**I'm a creator of the [Autoban](https://www.drupal.org/project/autoban) module and I believe I know how my module works.** You may be free to ask questions about my module on [the module issues](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/autoban). I added this question to the FAQ question also.

My previous right answer was deleted by [apaderno](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/199/apaderno) and I want to know why.

Comment: Was that on this Question? It is probably best to inquire at https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/